# Method accepts List<String>, needs to return same implementation of List<String>

Tags: java, list, inheritance, interface

I have a method that needs to accept any implementation of `List`, create a `newList` of the same implementation, and return the `newList`. I'm trying to figure out how to ensure that `newList` is of the same implementation of `List` as `input`. See the attached code:

```
static List<String> get(List<String> input){
  // do some stuff
  List<String> newList = new (?????);
  // do some stuff with newList
  return newList;
}
```

I can overload the method for `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `Vector`, etc. but I want to see if it can this be done without repeating a bunch of code.

Comment: Why do you need to return the same implementation?

Comment: do you want a copy of the list?

Comment: This violates the principle of OOP. The implementation should not matter. Anywhere else that hard-codes as a specific type of List should potentially be using the interface.

Comment: @Compass That is what I needed to hear. Seems like if it wasn't possible, there had to be a reason. Wish me luck while I go push back to the boss types.

Comment: If you need to target a specific implementation for a specific purpose, I would say that creating a method specifically for that purpose would be more appropriate, and then you can call the generic version and convert it over to the specific version inside the method.

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this

```
static List<String> get(List<String> input){
  // do some stuff
  List<String> newList = (List<String>)input.getClass().newInstance();
  // do some stuff with newList
  return newList;
}
```

`input.getClass()` will return actual runtime implementation type.

But this may not always work:

1. Implementation may have not accessible constructor
2. There may be no no-args constructors
3. You will have to introspect all issues by yourself
4. Many more possible troubles with that that I am not aware of

In general, don't do that. Don't stick to implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Method overloading is one way to go about it. *if possible*, why not let the user of this method specify the type of the list instead?

i.e. the `get` method now also consumes a `Supplier<List<String>>`:

```
static List<String> get(List<String> input, Supplier<List<String>> listSupplier){
        // do some stuff
        List<String> newList = listSupplier.get();
        // do some stuff with newList
        return newList;
}
```

Then one can do:

```
get(arrayList, ArrayList::new);
get(linkedList, LinkedList::new);
get(vector, Vector::new);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for my present issue but I will remember it because I will run into a situation where I can use it.